# What is the reason, that I have only unknow ip, and only one visitor in my awstats report?

Tags: awstats

I installed awstats and it looks in principle ok.

The only thing is, that I still have only one visitor with all the hits and only an "unknown ip" as addresses.

All other thinks (OS, browser etc.) look ok

Any Idea where to search?

Answer (score 1):

I was lazy with my apache2 configuration.

I put all vmhost log data into  `/var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log`

It is ok for me.

But then apache2 has a different log format.

A look at apache2.conf tells - look at `vhost_combined` and the %v:%p at the start :

```
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
```

And this does not fit to awstats

```
LogFormat=1 #that is:
#LogFormat = "%host %other %logname %time1 %methodurl %code %bytesd %refererquot %uaquot"
```

**Solutions:**

1. Make your log files less lazy and put them in a separate file in apache2 config (recommended)

or

2. Change the logfile format in apache2 to: `LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined` ie. remove the "%v:%p"

or

3. Change the logfile parameter in your awstats to: `LogFormat = "%other %host %other %logname %time1 %methodurl %code %bytesd %refererquot %uaquot"` ie. add an %other at the beginning of the line, to get rid of domain:port